# Получение и передача имени/фамилии на русском языке VK API

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Получаю информацию о юзере c помощью такого запроса:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_id="number"&v=5.52&lang=ru
```

Далее, отправляя сообщение юзеру с его именем, с помощью такого запроса:

```
"https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=number&message=" + name + "&access_token=1..5&v=5.52";
```

Ожидая сообщение в текстом "***Антон***", получаю сообщение с текстом "***?1??нтон***".
Если проблема с кодировкой, то почему только часть символов транслируется неправильно?
P.S. Пишу на java, сервер Microsoft Azure.

Comment: Возможно у вас какие-то не те символы в `name` попали? Попробуйте не `name`, но `name.trim()` передавать.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб 
К сожалению не помогает. 
При чтении другого имени или фамилии может не отображаться буква в любом другом месте

Comment: Быть может дело в том, как и откуда читаете? Откуда берётся имя? И как?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб А возможно ли такое, что принимая JSON от VK (не в UTF-8)  и сохраняя распарсенный JSON в String (в кодировке UTF-8)  происходит какой то сбой? Хотя в таком случае все символы были бы заменены

Comment: Не думаю, что такое возможно. В этом случае, действительно, должно всё испортиться... Попробуйте в логи повыводить что приходит и что отсылаете. Может что-то станет яснее. Также можно попробовать последнюю версию АПИ юзать - `5.68`

Comment: на серверной части приложения будет проще реализовать Ваш функционал через Java SDK (https://vk.com/dev/Java_SDK)

Comment: @DaysLikeThis спасибо, реализовал через Java SDK, все работает как надо)

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно в адресной строке заэнкодить кириллицу.
Должно получится вот так: `https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send?user_id=number&message=%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD&access_token=1..5&v=5.52'

В коде: `URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8");`
Надеюсь помог.

UPD:
Судя по всему нужен ещё хедер `content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8;`

Comment: Такой вариант тоже пробовал, получается вообще такая строка:  

    **Ð Ð½Ñ‚Ð¾Ð½**  

Такое чувство, будто ответ от  ВК приходит не в UTF-8.